# Will Scala interpreter acts as exactly as other interpreter?

Tags: scala, interpreter

I have doudt, Is scala interpreter(REPL) compiles the command and run by the JVM like how the scalac compiles a program ?

Simply Does it work like any other normal interpreter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard Scala interpreter, as experienced in the REPL for example, is a variant of the compiler that takes input, wraps it in an invisible object and compiles it on the fly (like any other regular Scala program), then runs the body of that virtual object.

The [Scala Meta](https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta) project might offer a different approach of a more direct interpretation without going through full-to-byte-code compilation.

Comment: which means , that scala interpreter is not pure interpreting language ?

Comment: I don't know what "pure" means here. The JVM interprets bytecode, browsers interpret JavaScript emitted from Scala.js. Not pure in the sense that there is no intermediate representation. For that you would need to evaluate the trees directly, as hinted at with Scala-Meta.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I got it.